# How to show related model fields when a foreign key is selected without submitting the form in django?

Tags: django, asynchronous, foreign-keys, admin

Say you have two models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    city = models.CharField(...)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', ...)
    text = models.TextField(...)
```

In django's admin interface, when creating (or editing) and Article, you get a drop down of the Authors listed by their name. When you select an Author (without pressing save), i want to see that Author's city as a readonly field. How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Via javascript. You'd also need to set up a view that knows how to return a that related author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via javascript. You'd also need to set up a view that knows how to return a that related author.

Example psuedo code jQuery

```
$(".my-admin-input").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path-to-my-view',
        data: { author: $(this).val() },
        success: function(response) { $(".author-city").val(response.author) })
    });
});

def my_view(request):
    return Author.objects.get(pk=request.GET['author']).city
```

You can sneak JS into django admins by...

- overloading admin templates
- overriding the relevant ModelAdmin template
  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options
- modifying the form class used in the admin and defining a Media class
  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/